# What is an exponent of an exponent called?

Tags: terminology, exponentiation

I came across an expression of Stretched Exponential Decay
$L/L_0 = \exp\left[-\left(\frac{t}{\tau}\right)^\beta\right]$,
and got curious. Is there a term to refer to an exponent of an exponent? To be more specific, is there any proper name for $z$ in $x^{y^z}$?

Comment: It's called double exponential function: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_exponential_function

Comment: Thanks, @Luthier415Hz. I saw this wiki page but it does not answer my question. I revised the question to be more specific.

Comment: There is definitely not any kind of standard name for this, and off-hand I can't ever recall having seen a locally-used name either, although I'm sure someone probably has done the latter somewhere in the mathematical literature. If you feel it necessary to make up a name for something you're preparing for publication, maybe in the case of $x^{y^z}$ use the term "first level exponent" for $y^z$ and "second level exponent" for $z.$ Note that this terminology can be easily extended to higher [power tower expressions](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PowerTower.html).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Thank you, it is helpful!